# Not calling glclear results in weird artifacts

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-3.0

im wanting to NOT call glClear for the depth or color bit because i want to be able to see all the previously rendered frames. And it does work except it repeats the model all over the x and y axis, and also causes some strange grey blocky lines. Is there a way to accomplish this? Im using opengl es 3 on android. Thank you for any help.

[image: uh]

Comment: So you don't want to clear away the previous frame, yet you are complaining about seeing the previous frame? You should probably decide if you want one or the other

Comment: I want it to work as i expect not be crazy. Im drawing a circle by rotating from one endpoint of a line, and i wanna keep the frames to see the whole circle draw

Comment: Did you simply forget to clear it the first time? You still should clear it once before you start drawing. But make sure that the scene is loaded, viewport set and buffers bound before you do so...

Comment: @MaticOblak a good idea. Should have thought of it myself. But sadly it did not fix it. But thank you, still.

Comment: This is a strange issue then. Can you at lest provide some image or video so we can see what is going on. Anyway this should work normally, there is no reason to clear a buffer and progressive drawing should work. Many applications use it that way.

Comment: @MaticOblak added to question. The bg is supposed to be white, and there should only be one circle.

Comment: Is this a FBO (frame buffer object)? Does it work correctly (beside seeing only last frame drawn) if you clear the buffer on every frame?

Comment: @MaticOblak no its not a fbo, and yes it does. Note that taking the screenshot affected it somewhat, making the bg black and the bars white when its actually the inverse

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143283/discussion-between-matic-oblak-and-colby-ray).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of the default framebuffer at the start of a frame is undefined, especially on tile-based renderers, which most of the mobile GPUs are. Your "repeats" in the X and Y axis are likely just showing how big the tiles are on your particular GPU (e.g. it's just dumping out whatever is in the GPU local tile RAM, repeated N times to completely cover the screen).

If you want to render on top of the previous frame you need to configure the rendering context configuration to use `EGL_BUFFER_PRESERVED` (the default is `EGL_BUFFER_DESTROYED`). E.g:

```
eglSurfaceAttrib(m_display, m_surface, EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR, EGL_BUFFER_PRESERVED);
```

Note 1: this will incur some overhead (the surface is effectively copied back into tile-local memory), whereas starting with a surface discard or invalidate, or a clear is usually free.

Note 2: this will only preserve color data; there is no means to preserve depth or stencil across frames for the default framebuffer.

Comment: Is this a setting that can be turned on and off during execution?

Comment: Yes, although it's usual to do it at context creation time (you normally alter the rendering algorithms you are using to exploit the preserve or destroyed state, so it's not always a setting you can trivially toggle on or off).

Comment: do you know how i get a an eglcontext? Its the first line thats crashing it

Comment: Using egl api 10 fixes the crashing but that api diesnt have a eglSurfaceAttrib